# php-mongo incompatible with php 7 on arch linux

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, php-7, arch

I want to work on a project that require mongodb and I'm using Arch Linux and php 7.3. When I installed Mongodb I discovered that the extension was removed since php 7.

Please what is the alternative now....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new driver is [MongoDB](https://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php). Not to be confused with the old [Mongo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php).